# Does the Galois groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic under `some suitable assumptions`?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E_1,~E_2$ be two elliptic curve on the $p$-adic field $K \supseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Consider the $p$-power torsion points and adjoin them with $K$.

Denote $E_i[p^n], ~i=1,2$ to be the set of $p^n$-torsion points of $E_i,~ i=1,2$,  where $n$ some positive integers.

Denote the extensions $K_n=K(E_1[p^n])$ and $K_n'=K(E_2[p^n])$.

`Case I:` Consider the corresponding Galois extensions $G_1=\text{Gal}(K_n/K)$ and $G_2=\text{Gal}(K_n'/K)$.

`Case II` More generally, If further assume $\Lambda=\bigcup_{p,n} E_1[p^n]$ and $\Lambda'=\bigcup_{p,n} E_2[p^n]$, then consider $G_1=\text{Gal}(K(\Lambda)/K)$ and $G_2=\text{Gal}(K(\Lambda')/K)$.

**My question-**

For both above two cases,

> If $n \to \infty$, does the Galois groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic under `some suitable  assumptions` ?

> Does $G_1$ and $G_2$ are map-able by a good map under `some suitable assumptions`  when $n \to \infty$?

Any intuitive idea, discussions are appreciated. Thanks